# How do I prevent Long / Int64 ToString() converting to Exponential Format?

Tags: c#, .net, long-integer, int64

Running .NET 4.6 and x64 build options.

No ToString() format option seems to work for numbers over 15 digits in length, as it converts them to Exponential Format.

What I have tried so far:

```
long.ToString("#");
long.ToString("G");
long.ToString("0");
long.ToString("#,#");
long.ToString("0,0");
```

The only thing that partially works is:

```
long.ToString("0,0");  //Ex.) 5,149,673,432,170,230
```

However, I would prefer a plain number. I would prefer not to use:

```
String.Replace(",", "");
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:
Solution was one already tried. .ToString("0")

Ran a full repair of VS2015 and Cleaned my solution.  It's now working as intended.

Comment: try `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: Will test this out shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "0" format.

```
long num = 1234567890123456789;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Str=" + num.ToString("0"));
```

Output: Str=1234567890123456789

Comment: @RagingCain Strange. Can you add this assertion to the sample code?  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(num.ToString("0") == "1234567890123456789");

Comment: I am running a repair on my Visual Studio, I think something is wrong.  Will comment soon if this worked.

Comment: @RagingCain is it possible that you are using/viewing this string somewhere else (ie, Excel) and that is changing the format?

Comment: Nothing like that, just a simple textbox with no maximum on character size.  Repair is still running.

BigInteger was working.  Just Long was "broken".

Comment: I like @Steve Wong's suggestion. See http://superuser.com/questions/413226/why-does-excel-treat-long-numeric-strings-as-scientific-notation-even-after-chan

Comment: hold on. What textbox? Is this  in a web page or form app? What textbox are you using to display this? If you check the string in the debugger, is it formatted incorrectly? Perhaps the textbox is formatting it like this.

Comment: It's working with a Clean Solution and full Repair of Visual Studio.  .ToString("0") was the correct string format option.

Answer (score 1):

If you've actually got a `long` or `ulong`, then

```
string s = long.MaxValue.ToString() ;
```

returns the expected string `"9223372036854775807"`.

While

```
string s = ulong.MaxValue.ToString() ;
```

returns the expected string `"18446744073709551615"`.

Are you *sure* you've dealing with a `long` and not some floating point type?

Comment: Yep, looks like a full repair of VS2015 resolved my issue. ToString("0") works correctly for me now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Int64 bigNumber =  9223372036854775806L;
String s1 = String.Format("{0:g}", bigNumber);
String s2 = bigNumber.ToString("G");
Debug.WriteLine("s1 = {0}, s2 = {1}", s1, s2);
```

writes:

> s1 = 9223372036854775806, s2 = 9223372036854775806